# Installing Komodo Edit on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, komodoedit

When running the install.sh

the following error occurs

```
install.sh: line 48: ./INSTALLDIR/lib/python/bin/python: Permission denied
```

Comment: change permission to install.sh to allow it to run as an executable.

Comment: @user189035 if you mean chmod +x install.sh, then yes I did that. Still the same effect

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, Yes I am

Comment: Maybe you should ask it in the general Linux (aka non-ubuntu) stackexchange ( http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ) I for one can't really help you more because i'm not using Fedora

Answer (score 2):

since the error got as far as line 48 the permission on install.sh is ok.

What is not OK is the permission on the python executable.

```
chmod +x ./INSTALLDIR/lib/python/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have python installed an it's even better if you have v2+ like the one Komodo IDE installer has integrated and to see what version of python you have installed just open your terminal/console and type "python" (without the quotation marks) and the output should be something like this:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And if you have python installed then open install.sh and search for a line similar to this:

```
$dname/INSTALLDIR/lib/python/bin/python -E $dname/support/_install.py "$@"
```

(I have Komodo IDE 8.0 so the code might differ) All you have to do is replace the path that points to the integrated python from the Komodo IDE installer "(Komodo IDE folder)/INSTALLDIR/lib/python/bin/python" with your local installed python which is "python" so in conclusion replace:

```
$dname/INSTALLDIR/lib/python/bin/python
```

With:

```
python
```

Result:

```
python -E $dname/support/_install.py "$@"
```

This technique worked for me however I was using Linux Mint 14 Nadia which by default comes with a preinstalled Python version 2.7.3 (like many other linux distributions out there) and my version of Komodo IDE was 8.0

EDIT:

The technique above seems to give an error about some missing python module named "activestate" which is a file named "activestate.py" located in the incorporated python from Komodo IDE installer however the second method I've used worked just fine.

First step is to open your terminal/console and obtain root privileges after that open your file manager/explorer mine was "nemo" so I typed "nemo" in the terminal/console (without the quotation marks) that opened a new window of nemo with Elevated Privileges aka. Root Privileges so the I've browsed to where I saved the archived Komodo IDE installer I've downloaded from the official site and opened with the default archive manager installed on my system (by default the archive manager also opened with root privileges inherited from nemo file manager) so in the file manager/explorer I've browsed to "/opt/" and extracted the contents of that archive in a folder then closed the archive manager now open a terminal/console window and obtain root privileges then cd into the folder where "install.sh" is located ex. "cd /opt/komodo-ide-8.0.0-linux-x86/" now type in the terminal/console

```
sh ./install.sh
```

Or

```
bash ./install.sh
```

And the rest of the installation should proceed as normal and require you the path where to install Komodo in my case I typed "/opt/komodo/" and the installation worked just fine.