# During Komodo Edit isntallation on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, komodoedit

I'm receiving this error when installing Komodo Edit?

```
ImportError: No module named activestate
```

In the install.sh fiel, I changed the python interpreter because I encountered [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361881/installing-komodo-edit-on-fedora)

So the changed part of the file now looks like this:

```
python -E $dname/support/_install.py "$@"
```

instead of this

```
$dname/INSTALLDIR/lib/python/bin/python -E $dname/support/_install.py "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have zero confidence that your default python executable would be able to complete the task at hand.  Komodo comes with it's own python interpreter (and site-packages dir) so they can make sure everything works.

Edit the install.sh back to what it was and check my answer to [your original posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361881/installing-komodo-edit-on-fedora)

short version: *change the permissions on the **python executable***